# Reading, looping and editing XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to read an xml file and take the two nodes to create a subchild. Here is the sample content of the xmlfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClaimBatch>
    <Claim>
      <chargeableCodeGroup>Consultation</chargeableCodeGroup>
      <schemeSurcharge>0</schemeSurcharge>
      <levy>00.00</levy>
      <code>M71.38</code>
      <qualifier>P</qualifier>
    </Claim>
  </Claim>
</ClaimBatch>

I want to read this file and take <Code> and <qualifier> add them to <diagnosis>. Below is an example of the desired output

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClaimBatch>
    <Claim>
      <chargeableCodeGroup>Consultation</chargeableCodeGroup>
      <schemeSurcharge>0</schemeSurcharge>
      <levy>00.00</levy>
      <Diagnosis>
        <code>M71.38</code>
        <qualifier>P</qualifier>
      </Diagnosis>
    </Claim>
</ClaimBatch>
```

I have tried the below code but its not working

```
Dim cNode As XmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ClaimBatch/Claims/Claim")
'Dim currNode As XmlNode
' Select the 3rd child node of <C>
Dim thirdChildNode As XmlNode = cNode.ChildNodes(24)
Dim docFrag As XmlDocumentFragment = xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment()
docFrag.InnerXml = "<Diagnosis>" + "</Diagnosis>"

' insert the availability node into the documentcurrNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
cNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, thirdChildNode
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: yes, this is too broad.... Do check the link from @Phaedra

Comment: basically what I am trying to do is to create a sub child in a claim, this sub child is called Diagnosis and within Diagnosis I want to have nodes <code> and <qualifier>

Comment: I have tried this code but its not working:

Dim cNode As XmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ClaimBatch/Claim")
                'Dim currNode As XmlNode
                ' Select the 3rd child node of <C>
                Dim thirdChildNode As XmlNode = cNode.ChildNodes(3)
                Dim docFrag As XmlDocumentFragment = xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment()
                docFrag.InnerXml = "<Diagnosis>" + "</Diagnosis>"

                ' insert the availability node into the documentcurrNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
            cNode.InsertAfter(docFrag, thirdChildNode

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work, using LINQ to XML.

```vb
For Each claim In xmlDoc...<Claim>
    claim.Add(
        <Diagnosis>
            <%= claim.<code> %>
            <%= claim.<qualifier> %>
        </Diagnosis>
    )
    claim.<code>.Remove()
    claim.<qualifier>.Remove()
Next
```

Comment: Hello Everyone,

I have managed to get it right. Thank you very much @ Mark

For Each claim In xmlDoc.<ClaimBatch>.<Claims>.<Claim>
claim.Add(
          <Diagnosis>
          <%= claim.<code> %>
          <%= claim.<qualifier> %>
          </Diagnosis>
          )
          claim.<code>.Remove()
          claim.<qualifier>.Remove()
Next